# notification in social network application

Tags: android

I am currently working on application like social networking. In this application if one user sends message or add request to any other user,so how can i achieve that.

For example,
There are two users,USER A & USER B. If USER A sends message to USER B, then the USER A should get the notification in his profile immediately.

So what should be the functionality at USER A side & USER B side. Please give me some idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using AJAX using the method onreadystatechange()

hope that helps

Comment: i don't know any thing about AJAX. I want to implement into android.

Comment: can you provide some stuff for that? So i will refer from that.

Comment: @Saurabh you can always refer this  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp  .... also i personally learned from this site get you going really fast http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/